# New to HTML and CSS, creating a webpage for class. Cannot get my ul to float right

Tags: html, css

Im really new to web design and i need to create a simple website for a class. For some reason no matter what i try my unordered list wont float right. please help! my unordered list will only stay on the left side of the page for some reason.

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>      
        <meta charset="UTF-8">    <title> PhiladelphiaEagles.com - Summary Page   </title>  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <a href="summary.html"> Go To Home Page </a>
        <h1 align="center">  Jacob Kaneff</h1>
        <h2> Website Evaluation: <a href="philadelphiaeagles.com" target="_blank"> - Summary Page </a> <h2>

        <figure>
  <img src="eagles.png" alt="Homepage screen shot" width="650" height="650">
    <figcaption align="center">Homepage Screen Shot</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <div id="wrapper">



        The official Philadelphia Eagle's website is your one stop for all things Philadelphia Eagles. Whether you want the Latest updates or want to participate in online discussions, this page is for you. Sponsered by the NFL, this page is beautifully laid out and is easily navigated. The news is always well written, and up to date with breaking news coming in daily. 


        </div>





        <ul>

                    <li>  <a href="summary.html"> Summary </a>             </li>
                    <li>  <a href="audience.html">  Audience </a>          </li>
                    <li>  <a href="task.html">  Task </a>                  </li>
                    <li>  <a href="navigation.html">  Navigation </a>      </li>
                    <li>  <a href="functionality.html"> Functionality </a> </li> 
        </ul>




        <footer>


        </footer>


    </body>


</html>
```

This is my css

```
body{
    background-color:gray; 
    color:#000000;
    width:910px;
    font-family:Georgia,Arial,Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}



figure {

float:right;
}

 #wrapper{float:left; width: 150px; border: 1px solid brown;  }

ul {
  float:right;
  border: 1px solid blue ;
  float: right;
}
```

li:link    {color:green;}
li:visited {color:green;}
li:hover   {color:red;}
li:active  {color:yellow;}

Comment: Assign some `width` to the `ul` element

Comment: Before you do anything, I'd redo your formatting =]

Here's a quick redo for you, I didn't fix the error, you can do that yourself.

http://paste.ofcode.org/QCi3Sfi4Us7PnX9QUNLYxf

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so there are a couple things going on you may want to change :D

1. `body{
               background-color:gray; 
               color:#000000;
               width:910px;
               font-family:Georgia,Arial,Serif;
               font-size: 12px;
   }`

Notice you have

> width:910px;

This will change the entire webpage to only take up 910 pixels of your browser window. You haven't aligned the body with the rest of the window so the whole thing stays left.

To fix this you can do a couple things, one solution is to change `width:910px;` to `width:100%;`

Another solution is to center your body, you can do this by adding the two following lines to the `body{}` css block

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

There are several other things going on in your page that need some looking into, such using the deprecated align="center" along with your css, but one step at a time. You're doing great, keep on chugging along!

Answer (score 1):

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p74bG/1/)

Just give your `ul` a `<ul class="right">`

Then in CSS

```
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's floated to the right already!
it says it in your css twice!

```
  ul {
  float:right;
  border: 1px solid blue ;
  float: right;
}
```

first you need to change that to

```
    ul {
  float:right;
  border: 1px solid blue ;
}
```

second maybe you want the li's floated right?
in this case it's a bit different:

```
ul li{
float:right;
}
```

but this will put your ul underneath the figure element!

In conclusion: Your ul is already floated to the right, reading from your css, but on a page it's hard to see because the figure element that contains an image will not let ul to be all the way on the right side of the page.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is width and float,
i just rewrite the code....

**html code like**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <title> PhiladelphiaEagles.com - Summary Page   </title> 
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="summary.html"> Go To Home Page </a>
        <h1 align="center">  Jacob Kaneff</h1>
        <h2> Website Evaluation: <a href="philadelphiaeagles.com" target="_blank"> - Summary Page </a> </h2>
        <div class="leftside">
            <figure>
                <img src="eagles.png" alt="Homepage screen shot" width="650" height="650">
                <figcaption align="center">Homepage Screen Shot</figcaption>
            </figure>

            <div id="wrapper">
        The official Philadelphia Eagle's website is your one stop for all things Philadelphia Eagles. Whether you want the Latest updates or want to participate in online discussions, this page is for you. Sponsered by the NFL, this page is beautifully laid out and is easily navigated. The news is always well written, and up to date with breaking news coming in daily. 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
            <ul>
                <li>  <a href="summary.html"> Summary </a>             </li>
                <li>  <a href="audience.html">  Audience </a>          </li>
                <li>  <a href="task.html">  Task </a>                  </li>
                <li>  <a href="navigation.html">  Navigation </a>      </li>
                <li>  <a href="functionality.html"> Functionality </a> </li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**css like**

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-color:gray; 
    color:#000000;
    width:910px;
    font-family:Georgia,Arial,Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
figure {
float:left;
}
#wrapper{float:left; width: 150px; border: 1px solid brown;  }
ul {
  border: 1px solid blue ;
  float: right;
}
.leftside { float:left; width:400px;}
.rightside{float:right; width:400px;}
</style>
```

Try this code...